# How can I create schema.ini file? I need to export my .csv file to datagridview

Tags: c#, csv, export

I want to export a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file to a datagridview. I need to create the file `schema.ini`. But I don't know, how can I create it?

There is my code:

```
    public DataTable exceldenAl(string excelFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(excelFile);
            string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(excelFile);
            string cmd = "Select * From [" + fileName + "$]";

            string cnstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly + "\\;Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=Yes;FORMAT=Delimited\"";
            OleDbConnection ocn = new OleDbConnection(cnstr);
            ocn.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(cmd,ocn);
            OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            adap.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        finally {
        }
    }


    private void btnExcelReader_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dosya;
        string cevap;
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        dosya = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
        ClsExcelReader er = new ClsExcelReader();
        cevap = er.exceldenAl(dosya).ToString();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = cevap;
        //listViewExcelOku.DataBindings =
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open up notepad and create a file similar to this:

```
[YourCSVFileName.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=CSVDelimited
DateTimeFormat=dd-MMM-yyyy
Col1=A DateTime
Col2=B Text Width 100
Col3=C Text Width 100
Col4=D Long
Col5=E Double
```

Modify the above file to fit your specific data schema.  Save it as SCHEMA.ini in the same directory where your *.CSV file is located.

Read this link ([Importing CSV File Into Database](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/Importing_CSV_Database_Schema.ini.aspx)), it is a good example to get you up and understanding how the Schema.ini works

Comment: Link died. https://stackoverflow.com/q/16438985/1012847 has a reference to some schema definition (Microsoft's). Not sure if an introduction somewhere is still available.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote these Excel formulas to generate the content of this file if you can get hold of the Excel sheet with column headers. It's pretty basic. Add and remove features as desired. It assumes all text with delimiters. Then insert the following formula (including all your options) in A2:

```
="[no headers.csv]
"&"ColNameHeader=false
"&"MaxScanRows=0
"&"Format=Delimited(;)
Col"&COLUMN()&"="&A1&" text
"
```

And the following formula in B2.

```
=A2&"Col"&COLUMN()&"="&B1&" text
"
```

Then drag to the right to get your basic schema.ini (rightmost cell). You can adjust options in the excel cell below the column name. Each column has it's own definition. I got closing and opening quotes in the result when copied to text file.