# Is there any specification for schema.ini files for CSV's

Tags: csv, schema

I am wanting to create a Schema.ini file to define a CSV file and cannot find a specification online after searching,

Does such a specification exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's [MSDN has a good article on schema.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For a csv file a bare-bones schema should look something like:

```
[filename.csv]
Format=CSVDelimited
```

You can, of course, add extra options like column names and data types (see the above link for details).

The `schema.ini` file needs to be in the same folder as the file you want to read.