# Getting unspecified error while Reading CSV file using OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: asp.net, console-application, impersonation, jet, oledbdataadapter

**Update 1 :** I think schema.ini is incorrect. Please refer to below question. 
The file (dsTextFile) has just one row of data but record count is zero. So it means it is not reading at all. This is with removing FMT altogether or with Delimi. I still get error if FMT is fixed though.  So, how do I create SCHEMA.ini or make sure schema.ini is correct?

```
    private bool LoadTextFile(string textFilePath, out string errorInfo) {
        errorInfo = String.Empty;

        try {
            string textFileFolder = (new System.IO.FileInfo(textFilePath)).DirectoryName;
            string textConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                                            "Data Source=" + textFileFolder + ";" +
                                            "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=No;FMT=Fixed\";";
            OleDbConnection textConnection = new OleDbConnection(textConnectionString);

            textConnection.Open();

            textFilePath = (new System.IO.FileInfo(textFilePath)).Name;
            string selectCommand = "select * from " + textFilePath;

            OleDbCommand textOpenCommand = new OleDbCommand(selectCommand);
            textOpenCommand.Connection = textConnection;

            OleDbDataAdapter textDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(textOpenCommand);
            Console.WriteLine("Trying to set textDataAdapter");

            int rows = textDataAdapter.Fill(dsTextFile); //This is where error is coming.

            Console.WriteLine("detail rows being filled");

            textConnection.Close();
            textConnection.Dispose();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex_load_text_file) {
            Console.WriteLine("error in loadTextFile is " + ex_load_text_file.Message.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Please find the above source where I am getting error 'UnSpecified" for below line.

UnSpecified Error is coming at below line
`int rows = textDataAdapter.Fill(dsTextFile)`

What could be the issue? I have checked user permissions on c:\windows\temp but no success.

This is a console application and I have even tried to add below code in app.config but no success yet.

```
<system.web>
<identity imperonate = "false"/> </system.web>
```

This is a legacy application but needs to run on windows server 2012 setup.

Answer (score 0):

You are using FMT=Fixed on the connection string, if you are not using a schema.ini, change it to FMT=Delimited and it will work.

i.e.:

```html
string textConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
"Data Source=" + textFileFolder + ";" +
"Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited\";";
```

Comment: Thanks for inputs. but the input file that I am reading is fixed length and not delimited. Does it matter here?

Comment: I suppose you are using a schema.ini file then ?

Comment: Yes I am using schema.ini file.

Comment: any inputs? I dont get the error as mentioned in original post if I changed FMT to be delimited but I am getting errors while parsing through the data further.

Comment: I think schema.ini is now incorrect. The file (dsTextFile) has just one row of data but record count is zero. So it means it is not reading at all. This is with removing FMT altogether or with Delimi. I still get error if FMT is fixed though.  So, how do I create schema.ini or make sure schema.ini is correct?

Comment: Try checking this schema.ini example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259562/how-can-i-create-schema-ini-file-i-need-to-export-my-csv-file-to-datagridview