# Defining OleDbCommand Return Type

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

I'm using the below OleDbCommand to read from a file method multiple times. The problem I'm having is that most of the time it's returning the datatypes as strings but occasionally (depending on the data being read) its returning int types. Is there a way to request all columns return as string without having to convert everything once it's loaded?

```
static DataTable GetDataTableFromCsv(string path, bool isFirstRowHeader)
    {
        string header = isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";

        string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

        string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "]";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
                  @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly +
                  ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);

            return dataTable;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you heard of ``LINQ``? This is the kind of thing you can do much more easily in LINQ.

Comment: @abhi Datatable from textfile? Would love an example given what I have above.

Comment: You need a schema file.  See following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259562/how-can-i-create-schema-ini-file-i-need-to-export-my-csv-file-to-datagridview.

Comment: abhi : Read the request : "all columns return as string without having to convert everything once it's loaded".  Using linq will convert after loading which is not what was requested.

Comment: @jweng thanks for the response. Problem I have is the files are different and I can't predict how many columns they will have so I can't create a one size fits all schema. I'm taking all these text files and merging them into one table that holds all the data + column headers. I really just want to specify that everything should be string.

Comment: @windowskm if the files are different, can you identify the columns in it based on the filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's necessary to execute this using an `OleDbCommand` then you could use an `OleDbDataReader` instead of a `DataTable` and read each value using [`GetObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx).

Then you can call `ToString()` on any of the values.

But if you have a CSV file containing untyped data then it might be much easier to just to read the file one line at a time and split the values, creating a `List<string[]>`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282999/reading-csv-file-and-storing-values-into-an-array) shows the simplest way to read a .csv and split each line.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542996/how-to-split-csv-whose-columns-may-contain) shows how to do it if the values contain commas within quotes that don't delimit values, like `this,are,separate,"this,is,one"`